# Select by latest date

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select statements where is fixed post id, group by user id and with latest date.  Here is what i have:

```
$bids = "SELECT uid, Max(date_made), bid FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."auction_bids WHERE pid=$pid GROUP BY uid";
```

In this query is problem only with date, it returns first results, but i need last.
Here is the screen of my database: 
[image: bd]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to obtain the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html):

```sql
SELECT uid, date_made, bid
FROM   ${wpdb->prefix}auction_bids NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   uid, MAX(date_made) AS date_made
  FROM     ${wpdb->prefix}auction_bids
  WHERE    pid = $pid
  GROUP BY uid
) AS t
WHERE  pid = $pid
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abd79/1/0).

Comment: Only max, not min. As i said - latest date. But answer is good, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

use min instead of max and grab the id, then join:

```
$bids = "SELECT ss.uid, ss.min, b.bid FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."auction_bids bid INNER JOIN (SELECT uid, MIN(date_made) as min FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."auction_bids WHERE pid=$pid GROUP BY uid) ss ON ss.uid = bid.uid";
```

It's not clear what you want from your English. Sorry.

Comment: Mmm, sorry, my english is poor as it is not my mother tongue, but i tried it as accurately as possible. What exactly you don't understood?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"SELECT pre.uid, pre.date_made, pre.bid
FROM ".$wpdb->prefix." AS pre
WHERE pre.pid = $pid AND date_made = 
    (SELECT MAX(pre2.date_made) FROM ".$wpdb->prefix." AS pre2 
    WHERE pre2.uid = pre.uid)
GROUP BY pre.uid";
```

A bit complicated but efficient. Similar to [eggyal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/623041/eggyal)'s answer but I'm using theta style coding and hence easy to understand.